# How would I select a specific number of characters in between a string in Google big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a field in my BQ table which is of type string and I need to select some characters in between them.

**What I have:**

student_details is the table, and details is the only field in the table and is of type STRING.

```
details
name:rishi;id=32a01a-2tf5-433a-7117-12323adfr2;dept:maths
name:vineeth;id=83faf-34fa-9912-afd-dsfeffef13fd;dept:science
```

I need only id in a separate field.

**what I want:**

(Basically I want characters after **id=** and before **;dept**)

```
details                                                            id

name:rishi;id=32a01a-2tf5-433a-7117-12323adfr2;dept:maths          32a01a-2tf5-433a-7117-12323adfr2
name:vineeth;id=83faf-34fa-9912-afd-dsfeffef13fd;dept:science      83faf-34fa-9912-afd-dsfeffef13fd
```

Could anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_extract()`:

```
select regexp_extract(details, ';id=([^;]+);') as id
```